# Can I file STEM extension on my 1st masters?

Tags: usa, visa, working

I did two masters degrees which both are in STEM courses. After the first masters was completed, I started my second masters and after completion of second masters I obtained OPT ON Basis of second masters degree wit IT management.

Now my question is: Can I file a STEM extension on the basis of my first masters degree, which is Environmental technology? I am getting a job in the field of my first master degree.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is [yes](https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/optional-practical-training-extension-for-stem-students-stem-opt#_Eligibility_for_the)!

> **Previously obtained STEM degrees:** If you are an F-1 student
> participating in a 12-month period of post-completion OPT based on a
> non-STEM degree, you may be eligible to use a previous STEM degree
> from a U.S. institution of higher education to apply for a STEM OPT
> extension. You must have received both degrees from currently
> accredited and SEVP-certified institutions, and cannot have already
> received a STEM OPT extension based on this previous degree. The
> practical training opportunity also must be directly related to the
> previously obtained STEM degree.
>
> For example: If you are currently participating in OPT based on a
> master’s degree in business administration but you previously received
> a bachelor’s degree in mathematics, you may be able to apply for a
> STEM OPT extension based on your bachelor’s degree as long as it is
> from an accredited U.S. college or university and the OPT employment
> opportunity is directly related to your bachelor’s degree in
> mathematics.

Another non-governmental website specifically said this was possible with 2 master's degrees.